# If $\ \frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}$ exist then$\ f$ as a function of$\ x$ is continuous at$\ x_0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

What I tried:

It's given that there exist
$$\ \frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_o) -f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$

So whe have to define$\ f$ as a function of$\ x$, that is $\ f(x,y_0)=\alpha(x)$.

We know that$\ \alpha(x)$ is differentiable at$\ x=b=(x_0,y_0)$, so:

$$\ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\alpha(b+h)-\alpha(b)}{h}=\alpha '(b)$$

So
$$\ \lim_{h\to 0}{\alpha(b+h)-\alpha(b)}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\alpha(b+h)-\alpha(b)}{h}·h=\alpha '(b)·0=0$$
Then
$$\ \lim_{h\to 0}\alpha(b+h)= \lim_{h\to 0}\alpha(b+h) -\alpha(b) +\alpha(b)=0+\alpha(b)=\alpha(b)$$

Thus, if$\ x=b+h$ then$\ h=x-b$

$$\ \lim_{h\to 0}\alpha(x)=\alpha(b)$$

Which implies that$\ \alpha(x)$ is continuous at$\ x_0$

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: basically, you are trying to prove the rather well-known fact, that differentiability (in the sense of one dimensional calculus) implies continuity, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to prove

Comment: well at first sight your proof seems okay to me, it'd be probably more convenient to just quote the already known one-dimensional machinery, to which I alluded in the upper comment.